# WSO2 API Manager adding a flow of multiple endpoints to a single request

Tags: rest, web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

Lately I've been asked to deal with a specific usecase using the API management tool **"WSO2 API-M"**

The goal of the use case is the following:

**For example** : We need to create a user, to do so our backend requires us to use a group of endpoints (creating id **then** the user **then** his relationship with a group..."

**the solution** : we need to group all these endpoints into a flow that gets called whenever we use call a defined resource

That way the front end devs need to only define a single path for that whole process.

Now my **Question** is; I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to WSO2 and I'm still not familiar with a lot of terms, but can someone tell me if this can be done with WSO2 ?

and if so give me a suggestion on how it can be done, I'm not requesting code, even a simple suggestion is enough

Thank you

Comment: Would recommend trying out WSO2 Enterprise Integrator for your use case. You can have a look at [Service Orchastration](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/exposing-several-services-as-a-single-service/) for an example

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to ask, can this be accomplished using the micro integrator ? I already have a kubernetes cluster setup and would rather work with what I have

Comment: Yes, it is possible